# How to make gcc report int to uint conversion

Tags: c, static-analysis, lint

How can I make gcc compiler report conversions from integers to unsigned integers?
Is there an option/arg which I can pass to gcc compiler to flag out such conversions?

Comment: Which conversions do you mean? Is `unsigned int u = 0;` is also an integer-to-unsigned?

Answer (score 6):

Use the flag: `-Wconversion` which will warn about conversions between signed and unsigned integers that may change a value.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @Morovaille Please post a code that you are trying to compile and that warning doesn't catch it.

Comment: @AlexLop. It does not catch it in C++. In C it works : I upvoted the answer.

Comment: Indeed if one does not want complaints about double->integer and such, one should use `-Wsign-conversion`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It seems that `-Wconversion` includes `-Wsign-conversion`

Comment: @Lundin it does; my point is that `-Wconversion` complains much much more than just `-Wsign-conversion` which should catch all the `signed->unsigned`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/aCl11P for gcc it also needs `-Wsign-conversion`. For `clang` it is included in `Wconversion`

Comment: @bolov gcc: In C, this option is enabled also by -Wconversion.

Comment: @2501 oh, ok. Missed the `C` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-Wconversion`:

> `-Wconversion` Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value.
>   This includes......; conversions between signed and unsigned, like
>   unsigned ui = -1.

Or, more specifically, `-Wsign-conversion`:

> `-Wsign-conversion` Warn for implicit conversions that may change the sign of an integer value, like assigning a signed integer expression
>   to an unsigned integer variable. An explicit cast silences the
>   warning. In C, this option is enabled also by `-Wconversion`.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options